Why was my edit rejected if it improves the question's readability?
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1272732

The edit split up the wall of text, which usually deters answerers from even reading the post. The Markdown text was paragraphed and indented, which shows that the original author intended it to be paragraphed but they misunderstood how this would be rendered.
I didn't edit too thoroughly, so I expected that reviewers might choose to "Approve and edit". But why was it Reject[ed] and Edit and by a bot, to boot?

I want to say community rejecting is the OP's rejection but I need to check on that before committing to saying that's the truth

AH, never mind, that was a concequence of reject and edit https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit

One reason I would have rejected that particular edit is due the fact none of the grammatical errors were fixed.

@Ramhound so you would have "Reject and Edit"-ed in that case?

@Robotnik—Yes, I loaded the content into Grammarly, and it discovered five dozen issues. This does not even include how it would have rewritten some statements. The capitalization of the first word in every paragraph is weird. For instance, "Won't bother posting the manuals ...." isn't proper English.

So... here's what happened. OP rejected and edited, and that overrode the one accept. Since OP dosen't need their edit reviewed, your edit was declined in favour of OP's edit. This triggered a bit rejection vote and the OPs.
Admittedly a little clear as mud, but its both no fault  of your own (your edit was perfectly fine), and the system working as designed.

It's actually fine, though I was confused why it doesn't show who rejected my edit - I thought the review time expired or something.

Its less than obvious until you realise OP rejected it :D. Which took me more than a moment
